# SQL - dont show results if all 'count case when' statements return 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, null

I have a SQL statement that has multiple  'count case when' statements my issue is I don't want to show results in all results are null

if a source description returns null for all four count statements I don't want to show the source description row. i'm stuck and not sure how this can be achieved

any advice would be greatly appreciated

here is my sql

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('**-**', SourceDescription) > 0 then 
SourceDescription
WHEN CHARINDEX('-', SourceDescription) > 0 THEN
LEFT(SourceDescription, CHARINDEX('-', SourceDescription)-1) else
SourceDescription END as 'Source',

count(case when StartDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)    THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as 'Total',
count (case when CompletionDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)as 'Completed',
count (case when ClosedDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) and CompletionDate is null then 1 ELSE null END)as 'Closed',
count (case when ExchangeDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)then 1 else NULL END)as 'Exchanged'

from 
CASE_record with (nolock)
inner join case_warehouse  with (nolock)  on CASE_record.casekey = case_warehouse.casekey
WHERE  TypeCode = 'b'

group by CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('**-**', SourceDescription) > 0 then 
SourceDescription
WHEN CHARINDEX('-',SourceDescription) > 0 THEN
LEFT(SourceDescription, CHARINDEX('-', SourceDescription)-1) else
SourceDescription END
```

Comment: Case expressions, not case statements...

Answer (score 1):

You could just include each of the predicates in your where clause to ensure you only return records that match at least one criterion:

```
WHERE   TypeCode = 'b'
AND (   StartDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
    OR  CompletionDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
    OR  (ClosedDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND CompletionDate IS NULL)
    OR  ExchangeDate = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
    )
```